# VirtueMart Custom Fields (SKU)

Tags: mysql, joomla, session-variables, virtuemart

I'm a pretty novice programmer, but here is what I am trying to do, and what I've done so far:

What I want:

I'm trying to get a final SKU in the cart, built from the product's variant selections.

For an example, if the initial product is "Shovel", and it's SKU is "SHO", the cart variants selection SKU number adds to the end.

If one of the variants were:

Handle Color
-- Green Handle (with SKU of SKU1)
-- Yellow Handle (with SKU of SKU2)

The final SKU would be SHO - SKU1  if green were chosen, and SHO - SKU2 if yellow was chosen)

This would then create a session variable to pass onto the cart, and the cart would display this variable and I'd be able to pass it to an email notification, or anything I need after.

What I've done:

I've added a column custom_sku to the cart variant data in the table virtuemart_product_customfields. I've also added this field to the customs.php file in the administrator tables folder (/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/tables)

This field now updates into the database and each time you add a cart variant option, it adds an SKU to the column "custom_sku" for the row of the customfield_id:

Screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/02e1sfsef9

I've also modified the function getProductCustomsFieldCart in customfields.php (administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models) to add this into the option drop down value.

Now a value looks like: "Variant Value - $1.00 - SKU1"

What I'm stuck on:
I need to pass this SKU value, or the value of the option over to the cart, and have it so I can use this for remaining parts of the order.

This should most likely be done with a session variable, which looks like:    sessionSKUselect = "20"   where 20 is the custom field ID so I can use this in a query on the cart.

This can also be output in a session variable in an array, as long as it works.

There is currently a variable passed through the form that looks like: "customPrice[0][1]"  (the numbers pertain to which select list, and its variant group (which select list))

The customPrice[0][1] has a value of the customfield ID (just a number, for the database value. I need this value to be an array, or be able to use this array in the cart, to query a final SKU number.

Does anyone know what I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know how to utilize the cart variants. Each can be assigned a price. I have also made it so each variant option can be assigned a custom SKU (item number) as well, and the variable is in the same database table.

I've found out how to pull the variables using the function calculateModificators

Pretty much I needed the selected option values on the cart page, and this function makes them available. I've added my own little code into the above function, and now I can output the SKU but need to display it in an array.

Here is the code, I've noted where my additions are using comments.

```
    $query = 'SELECT  C.* , field.*
                    FROM `#__virtuemart_customs` AS C
                    LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_customfields` AS field ON C.`virtuemart_custom_id` = field.`virtuemart_custom_id`
                    WHERE field.`virtuemart_customfield_id`=' . $selected;
                $this->_db->setQuery($query);
                $productCustomsPrice = $this->_db->loadObject();
                $productCustomsSKU = $this->_db->loadObject(); // My Addition
                echo $productCustomsSKU->custom_sku. ' + '; // My Addition
```

So if my two SKU numbers are this, in order of selected options (SKU3, SKU1)

I get an output like SKU3SKU1

Now I need to get this value to look like this in the end:

- SKU3 + SKU1

This needs to have a + in the beginning of the string, and no + at the end. I need this to be in a value in the end, so my value will be:

$value = " + SKU3 + SKU1" and do this for every value that comes from the above array.